# Remove character from resultset in Java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I have a problem with a value from my Sql `ResultSet` in Java.
This value has a single quote (') and that is not valid value. The correct value will be a comma (,). 
I want to change this single quote(') for a comma (,).

Example of erroneous value: `7'8`

Example of the expected result: `7,8`

Example of my query and my ResulSet:

```
 String query = "SELECT width,height FROM SizeTable;";
 rs = st.executeQuery(query);

 while(rs.next()){
    String width = rs.getString(1);
    String height = rs.getString(2); <--- Here is on I get the error
 }

 String insert = "INSERT INTO SizeTable2 (Value1,Value2) VALUES('"+width+"','"+height+"')";

 st.executeUpdate(insert);
```

After running I get a SQL message that indicates me an invalid syntax error in my SQL statement ( I want to "Insert Into" width and height value).
I can't change this character with MySQL, only with Java.

Comment: Maybe you should tell us what error you get?

Comment: I still don't understand if the error is in the SQL statement or in its result

Comment: Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) before attempting to ask more questions.

Comment: Have fun with the SQL Inject Attacks with that code! Learn to use `PreparedStatement` asap.

Comment: I'm getting an error relating to this incorrect character ('), I want to change this for a comma (,) with Java.

Comment: You need to fix the data input. You should be able to code assuming that your database has no errors. You need to fix the data, not your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `String::replace` when you get your input :

```
String height = rs.getString(2).replace("'", ",");
```

---

You have to declare your variables outside the loop so you can use them later :

```
String width = "";
String height = "";
while(rs.next()){
    width = rs.getString(1);
    height = rs.getString(2).replace("'", ",");
}
```

---

Now your sql is open to SQL Injection or Syntax error, to avoid this i suggest to use PreparedStatement instead :

```
String insert = "INSERT INTO SizeTable2 (Value1,Value2) VALUES(?, ?)";

try (PreparedStatement insert = connection.prepareStatement(insert)) {
    insert.setString(1, width);
    insert.setString(2, height);
    insert.executeUpdate();
}
```

---

**Note** you can insert an empty values so i suggest to check the values before the insert :

```
if(!width.isEmpty() && !height.isEmpty()){
  //prepared statement
}
```

**second thing**, i assume that we use real number for width and height so why you are using strings instead, i suggest to change your data type so you can avoid all this problems.

Comment: You still have the same answer. the java solution which was deleted by you before some time.

Comment: @PradeepSingh please read the second note and can you clarify what did you mean, i really don't get you

Comment: YCF_L, I have more values apart from 7'8.
This will correct all invalid character in my fields or just this?

Thanks also for the SQL Injection info!!! ;)

Comment: @JohnStonecutter it will correct only the last value, if you want to change every thing then you have to move the insert part inside your while loop so you can replace and insert all the new values, but be careful